What is the Italian BTP yield calculation in last period?
I chose this example becuase it highlight two aspects I can't reverse engineer and can't find any official source documentation.
BTP: IT0005518128: 1/Nov/2022 -> 1/May/2033 at 4.4%.
If this bond is traded for settlement 1/Nov/2032 with price 99.0, then there is only one single full coupon period remaining.
There are different yield calculations one can make:

Annual: $99.0 = 102.2 * (1+y)^{-0.5} \implies y = 6.569126%$
Money-Market: $99.0 = 102.2 * (1+\frac{182}{360}y)^{-1} \implies y = 6.393606%$


How is the True Yield or Equiv 2/Yr Yield value calculated? I have asked Bloomberg help and their documentation is vague and contradictory.
I observe:

1/May/2033 is a holiday, the cashflow is settled on 2/May/2033.
The ICMA yield conversion formula is: $1+y_a = (1+y_s/2)^2 \implies y_s = 6.464646%$
If one tries to fudge these formulae around to account for 182/365 actual days, cannot arrive at 6.429702%.

